# Checking if values ​exist within string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have such string:
'Oracle Database Token: xxxx.';

I need to return true or false if xxxx is one of three variants:

- 1 or 11 or 111 or 1111 or 11111 or 111111 etc.
- character '-'
- number 123456789

I tried to build a regular expression for the `regexp_substr()` function but it turned out to be very hard.

Is this possible in a regular expression?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you want to identify and what you don't.  And isn't the first and third the same thing?

Comment: I need identify values betwen 'Token: ' and ','

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRANSLATE` to test for the first condition and the other two are simple tests for equality:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  token = 'Oracle Database Token: -.'
OR     token = 'Oracle Database Token: 123456789.'
OR     (   token <> 'Oracle Database Token: .'
       AND TRANSLATE( token, '_1', '_' ) = 'Oracle Database Token: .' )
```

**Sample Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( token ) AS
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: -.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: 123456789.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: 1.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: 111.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: 111111.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: 12111.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oracle Database Token: -12.' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query Output**:

> ```
> | TOKEN                             |
> | :-------------------------------- |
> | Oracle Database Token: -.         |
> | Oracle Database Token: 123456789. |
> | Oracle Database Token: 1.         |
> | Oracle Database Token: 111.       |
> | Oracle Database Token: 111111.    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee04e29b14a42884263c98660eeb72d1)*

---

You could also write it as a regular expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( token, '^Oracle Database Token: (1+|123456789|-)\.$' )
```

But simple string functions/comparisons might be quicker.

Comment: Can you help me with convert to REGEXP_SUBSTR? select REGEXP_substr( 'Oracle Database Token: 123456789.', '^Oracle Database Token: (1+|123456789|-)\.$', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual not working

Comment: @geekcode You want `SUBSTR( token, 24, LENGTH( token ) - 24 )` or `REGEXP_SUBSTR( token, '^Oracle Database Token: (1+|123456789|-)\.$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )` for example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=478bf1d3231961cbc4f41ca9e0000fc4)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where regexp_like(suchstring, '^Oracle Database Token: ([0-9]+|-)[.]'
```

EDIT:

If you want those specific numbers:

```
where regexp_like(suchstring, '^Oracle Database Token: (1+|-|123456789)[.]'
```

Comment: This will match tokens like `123` and not just `123456789` or repeated `1`s.

Comment: @MT0 . . . I interpreted the third item as just any numbers.  I guess you're right that it refers to that one particular number.